# What's the minimal set of characters I need to filter before passing a string to a system call?

Tags: perl, security

Assume that the following Perl code is given:

```
my $user_supplied_string = &retrieved_from_untrusted_user();
$user_supplied_string =~ s/.../.../g; # filtering done here
my $output = `/path/to/some/command '${user_supplied_string}'`;
```

The code is clearly insecure, but assume that the **only** thing that can be changed is the filtering code on line #2.

My question:

- What is the **minimal** set of characters that needs to be filtered on line #2 to make the above code secure?

Please note:

- Whitelisting is not an option in this case, so please keep your answer focused on what to filter out to make it secure. And more specifically; what is the minimal set of characters to filter out to make it secure? Everything else is off-topic.
- Make sure your answer addresses the question stated ("What is the **minimal** set of characters that needs to be filtered on line #2 to make the above code secure?"). If your answer does not address that very specific question then don't post. Thanks.

Comment: You might get some help by starting here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Laundering-and-Detecting-Tainted-Data

Comment: Here too: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html

Comment: You might get more responses if you explained the reasons for those somewhat odd constraints.  On the face of it, some people might think this is a homework question.

Comment: Adam: I'm trying to understand `` semantics and security in detail. If you consider that a homework question, well.. I'd like to sign up to that perl university!

Comment: @knorv:  I said "some people", not me. :)  I am only trying to help you phrase your question so that you can get the informaiton you want.

Comment: @knorv There is no one minimal set.  Everything is dependent on what shell will actually be used.  The solution is to side step the problem by avoiding the shell entirely as I did in my answer.  Anything else is a dangerous hack.

Comment: That's as  much security as you care to have? Why even bother then?

Comment: If you're trying to understand the issues here, then the Security chapter in Mastering Perl is the place to look, along with the aforementioned docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, given that you are concerned with security, I suggest you look into [taint mode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode).  As for the minimal set of characters to allow to be visible to shell, you are better off not letting any characters be seen by the shell:

```
my $output = do {
    local $/;
    open my $pipe, "-|", "/path/to/some/command", $user_supplied_string
        or die "could not run /path/to/some/command: $!";
    <$pipe>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little research, the following **may** be the minimal set you're looking for, at least on a subset of UNIX-like systems. Of course, I have not personally tested it, so YMMV:

```
    &;`'\"|*?~<>^()[]{}$\n\r
```

In a regex:

```
    s/[\&\;\`\'\\\"\|\*\?\~\<\>\^\(\)\[\]\{\}\$\n\r]//g
```

I don't think actually using this in real code would be a good idea, but I can see how it could be interesting out of pure curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

The set of characters that you allow depend on what the application in that system call is going to do with them. There's the shell special characters, but that's ony one part of the problem. You also have to ensure that the value you give to the command is valid input, and that requires some more work.

See, for instance, my chapter on security in [Mastering Perl](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527242/) where I go into the gory details of the problem.

Perhaps you can explain why your problem ties both your hands behind your back and blindfolds you. Your problem isn't technical if those are your constraints.